# Pasar argumentos por línea de comandos en Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Buenas, estoy en una de esas que la cosa mas tonta del mundo no funciona. A ver si alguien me puede decir porque...

Código de prueba:

```
public class Xxx {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        int nArgs = args.length;
        System.out.println( "Args introducidos: " + nArgs );
        
        if ( nArgs > 0 ) {
            for ( int i = 0; i < nArgs; i ++ ) {
                System.out.println( i + 1 + ". " + args[i] );
            }
        }
    }

} //class
```

Usando Netbeans 8.2 en Windows.

Para introducir los argumentos:

1. Clic derecho sobre el icono del proyecto en el ventana de proyectos
   a la derecha.
2. Selecciono Propiedades / Ejecutar
3. Introducí los valores en el campo de entrada "Argumentos", separando
   con espacios. He probado con un número, con un hola, el hola entre
   comillas... Como tengo varias clases en pruebas, tambien he indicado
   la clase Xxx como clase principal, por si acaso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Salida del programa:
>
> **Args introducidos: 0**

Siempre es la misma salida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Para hacer que funcione el paso de parámetros en la ejecución de tu
   programa, tienes que ejecutar el programa o proyecto y no el archivo
   de la clase. Recuerda que le estas pasando argumentos al programa y
   no a la clase, si no, no aparecerá nada. Para ello dale clic derecho
   al proyecto (como cuando ibas a agregar parámetros) y pulsa
   *Ejecutar*.
2. Con respecto al tipo de parámetros, son de tipo *String* separados por
   espacios y no necesitan comillas.

Comment: Gracias, buena puntualización.